# how to redirect all subdomains to another with parameter after the trailing slash using htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

If I use anything in wildcard it's redirecting me to `example.com/shop`. But what I want is when someone uses `anything.example.com/code` he redirects to `example.com/shop/code`. The current setting is redirecting me to `example.com/code/shop` if I use anything after the trailing slash in my case it's `code`.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.(example\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI}/shop [R=301,L,NE]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would seem to just need to reverse the `%{REQUEST_URI}/shop` part in the *substitution* string... (?)

For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.(example\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1/shop%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

The `REQUEST_URI` server variable contains the full URL-path (only) that the user requested, including the slash prefix.

You will need to clear your browser cache before testing. (Preferably test first with 302 temporary redirects to avoid caching issues.)