# Htaccess 301 Redirect with Parameter

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm stuck with an 301 redirect in htaccess. I'd like to redirect from

```
https://subdomain.example.com/SOME_STRING
```

to

```
https://www.example.com/folder/SOME_STRING
```

The string can be different on any request. Can someone help me out here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If these two hostnames point to the same place then you'll need to use mod_rewrite in order to check the hostname being requested.

Try the following at the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.(example\.com) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1/folder%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

The `%1` backreference matches the `example.com` in the preceding *CondPattern* - this simply saves repetition. The `REQUEST_URI` server variable contains the full URL-path from the request, including the slash prefix.

In fact, this is almost identical to another recent question that matches *any* subdomain:
[how to redirect all subdomains to another with parameter after the trailing slash using htaccess?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63152513/how-to-redirect-all-subdomains-to-another-with-parameter-after-the-trailing-slas)

To hardcode the hostname in the *substitution* string (as mentioned in comments) then you would do the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com/folder%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Most likely the target host name does not have to be specified using a capture reference. Most likely it can be specified in a literal, fixed way.

Comment: @arkascha Yes, you can hardcode the target hostname it if that is preferable (I've updated my answer). However, capturing the domain name saves having to repeat the domain name in the _substitution_ string (as I mentioned). Avoiding repetition is generally preferable, but it's really just personal preference in this case.